# How do I resolve the cross domain Access is denied issue in IE9?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, http, internet-explorer

I am working on an Angular project that requires cross domain requests. Everything works except I get the "Access is denied" error in IE9. I have done research and tried the following:

xhr-xdr-adapter.js : I include it after jQuery and before my Factory as instructed by their documentation but I get a Syntax error xhr-xdr-adapter.js(1,1) in the IE9 console.

```
<!--[if lt IE 10]>
   <script src="scripts/xhr-xdr-adapter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

jquery.transport.xdr.min.js : This just doesn't seem to do anything. I get the same behaviour as if it wasn't included at all.

Here are examples of my requests in my Factory. I use a mixture of ajax and http depending on what API I'm posting to.

```
PostSomething: function (_data) {
                return $http({
                    url : 'url...',
                    method : 'POST',
                    contentType : 'application/json',
                    dataType : 'json',
                    data : JSON.stringify(_data)
                })
            },

PostSomethingElse: function (_data) {
                return $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : 'url...',
                    dataType : 'json',
                    data : _data,
                    success : function (data) {
                        return data;
                    },
                    error : function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        return xhr;
                    }
                })
            },
```

What is the best way to reslove this in 2016?

Comment: what about other browsers? do you get the response?

Comment: Yes it works in all browsers, even IE10 +. Only Problem is with IE9 and lower. But I am only catering for IE9 so I don't care much for anything older